# Describe the rational solutions to this quartic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

Consider the quartic
                                                                                 $-(a^5 + b^5)x^4 + (4a^5 - b^5)x^3 - (6a^5 + b^5)x^2 + (4a^5 + b^5)x - (a^5 + b^5) = 0$ where $a$ and $b$ are nonzero fixed integers.

By inspection, one can quickly find that $(a, b, x)= (a, -a, 0)
$ is a trivial rational solution. But are there any other  ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about
the coefficient
of $x$?
All the other terms have
$-b^5$;
that is the only one with $b^5$.

$-(a^5 + b^5)x^4 + (4a^5 - b^5)x^3 - (6a^5 + b^5)x^2 + (4a^5 + b^5)x - (a^5 + b^5) 
= 0
$

Anyway,
I will try to simplify it
and see what happens.

$\begin{array}\\
-(a^5 + b^5)x^4 + (4a^5 - b^5)x^3 - (6a^5 + b^5)x^2\\
\quad + (4a^5 + b^5)x - (a^5 + b^5) 
&=-a^5x^4 + 4a^5x^3 - 6a^5x^2 + 4a^5x - a^5\\
&\quad-b^5x^4  - b^5x^3 -b^5x^2 + b^5x -  b^5\\
&=-a^5(x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x +1)
-b^5(x^4  +x^3 +x^2 -x +1)\\
&=-a^5(x-1)^4
-b^5(x^4  +x^3 +x^2 -x +1)\\
&=-a^5(x-1)^4
-b^5(x^4  +x^3 +x^2 +x +1)+2b^5x\\
&=-a^5(x-1)^4
-b^5(x^5-1)/(x-1)+2b^5x\\
\end{array}
$

Eh.

Wolfy gives four incredible complex expressions
for the roots
and
$x=0$ and $a=-b$ and $b \ne 0$.

By the rational root theorem,
any rational root
$r = p/q$
must have
$p | a^5+b^5$
and
$q | a^5+b^5$.
Since
$a^5+b^5
=(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4)
$,
we can try
$a+b$ and
$1/(a+b)$.
Neither seems to work.

That's all, folks.

Comment: I just copied and pasted your equation prefixed by "solve" and postfixed by "for x" and hit return. Very useful for lazy people like me.

For your second question, I would say just try it and see what happens.